# Shell script: Remove first and last double quote (") from all strings in a file

Tags: regex

I want to remove all outer double quotes from a file and merge multiple empty lines to 1 single line.

For example,

```
"UPDATE TableA 
 SET country_code = "FR",
 WHERE name = "A";



"
"UPDATE TableA 
 SET name = "A's B"
 WHERE country_code = "FR";



"
```

to

```
UPDATE TableA 
 SET country_code = "FR",
 WHERE name = "A";

UPDATE TableA 
 SET name = "A's B"
 WHERE country_code = "FR";
```

How could I do that? Thanks!

Note: I tried this sed command

```
sed -e 's/^"\|"$//g' test.sql > test_output.sql
```

However, it also removes all last double quotes within the where clause.

Comment: The ending `"` in `SET name = "A's B"` matched `"$`.

Comment: WHen I try this it doesn't do anything to the `WHERE` clauses. The only problem is with `"A's B"`

Comment: In your example the ending quotes are also at the beginning of lines. So try just replacing `^"` not `"$`

Comment: `sed  's/^"//' file | sed '/^$/N;/^\n$/D'`

Comment: Thank you! With that it can work well!

Comment: How is the script supposed to differentiate between "outer" double quotes and others?  I think you mean that double quotes that appear at the beginning of a line pair with each other but not with any other double quotes, and that it is these you want to remove.  Is that correct?  Is it safe to assume that the double quotes you want to retain will never appear at the beginning of a line?

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -00ne 's{\A[\s"]+|[\s"]+\z}{}g; print "$_\n\n" if $_;' test1.txt
```

```
UPDATE TableA 
 SET country_code = "FR",
 WHERE name = "A";

UPDATE TableA 
 SET name = "A's B"
 WHERE country_code = "FR";
```

`s{\A[\s"]+|[\s"]+\z}{}g;` Remove (substitute with an empty string) the following patterns: *either* the beginning of the string (`\A`) followed by one or more of either whitespace (`\s`) or a double quote (`"`) *or* the same at the end of the string (`\z`).

The regex uses this modifier:
`/g` : Match the pattern repeatedly.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-00` : Read the file in paragraphs, instead of one line at a time.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: How does reading it in paragraphs work for this input? There's a paragraph break between the end of the query and the ending `"` around that query. So the next paragraph begins with two `"`.

Comment: @Barmar The paragraphs that begin with two double quotes is trimmed by the one-liner because of `\A[\s"]+` in `s{\A[\s"]+|[\s"]+\z}{}g;`. That is, multiple double quotes at the beginning or the end of the paragraph are removed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu-awk` you could do this:

```bash
awk -v RS='(^|\n)"[^;]*;[^"]*"' '{
   print gensub(/(^|\n)"\s*|\s*"$/, "\\1", "g", RT)}' file

UPDATE TableA
 SET country_code = "FR",
 WHERE name = "A";

UPDATE TableA
 SET name = "A's B"
 WHERE country_code = "FR";
```

Regex pattern `(^|\n)"[^;]*;[^"]*"` matches a quoted block that must contain a single `;` as shown in OP's input.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I tried this sed command
>
> ```
> sed -e 's/^"\|"$//g' test.sql > test_output.sql
> ```
>
> However, it also removes all last double quotes within the where
> clause.

Well yes, the `|"$` part of the pattern in your substitution sees to that.  It's not clear to me what purpose that was ever supposed to serve.  Additionally, it doesn't appear that that would coalesce empty lines.

But this `sed` solution will do both:

```
sed -e 's/^"//; :1; $ { s/^.*\n//; n; }; /^[[:space:]\n]*$/ { N; s/\n"//; b1; }; s/^.*\n/\n/' \
  test.sql > test_output.sql
```

A more legible form of that `sed` expression would be:

```
# Remove an "outer" quote if this line contains one
s/^"//

:1
# On the last line, collapse any accumulated blank lines and terminate
$ { s/^.*\n//; n; }

# If the pattern space contains only whitespace and newlines then
#   - append a newline plus the next line of input
#   - remove an outer quote, if any, from the added text
#   - branch to label 1, above
/^[[:space:]\n]*$/ { N; s/\n"//; b1; }

# If there are any newlines in the pattern space then remove everything through
# the last one
s/^.*\n/\n/

# No more commands: print the pattern space, replace it with
# the next line, and go back to the beginning
```